# Hibernate: dynamically set table name

Tags: hibernate

I have an entity which should be dynamically persisted to different tables according to some string property representing the table name. Hibernate's Dynamic Models looks like exactly what I want, but I cannot find how to set table name :) Can anybody tell me what I'm missing? Thank's in advance.

P.S.Another found solution is http://java.dzone.com/articles/hibernate-dynamic-table-routin . But I dislike it cause it looks like dirty hack. What if I'll have multiple query parts named as the substring I want to replace.

Comment: The whole entity must go to another table, or just a subset?

Comment: There is a POJO. E.g. class Person. I want to save and retrive the instanceses of this class from multiple tables. E.g. from BAD_PERSONS_TABLE, GOOD_PERSONS_TABLE. Tables have the same structure. There are hundred+- of such tables which are created dynamically at runtime. According to our DB design and performance predictions it's the best approach. Don't try to force me to switch to another one)) Thanks!

Comment: No, I use Hibernate's XML mapping files.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `JPA then` you can `@PrePersist`.

If working with plain `Hibernate` then take a look at [event](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/events.html).

Don't know if it will work for you.

It looks like a `NamingStrategy` tutorial is what you need.

```
@Override
public String classToTableName(String className) {
    // your code super.classToTableName()
}


org.hibernate.cfg.NamingStrategy interface.
```

Hibernate 3.6 has four implementations of this interface:

```
org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultComponentSafeNamingStrategy
org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultNamingStrategy
org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy
org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
```

Implement your code to return the table name.

Comment: Hmm I also found this approach. The question is how can I determine table name using class name if my class name is always the same. Possible solution is to save the table name elsewhere before persisting to DB and then to retrive it. But I need to save/retrive the entities concurrently at the same time and I don't want to reduce my performance using syncronization. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Tried. The solution didn't work for me because NamingStrategy implementation is invoked only during Hibernate initialization. Currently I'm using the dirtyhack solution mentioned in my main post, but actually I dislike it and still looking for another one.

Answer (score 0):

This more like an schema design issue, those tables with similar definition and only name is different due to some attribute, why not add this attribute into the table schema and combine all those tables into one? Then you just need add this field into a where clause.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 0):

I tried a lot of ways, only it was the simplest:

```
Session session = super.getSession();
    SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery("raw sql");
    query.setParameter(":abc", "value");
    query.addEntity(Some.class);
    return query.list();
```